# Exception Class not found

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a `program UCanAccess.java`. I am getting the following exception when i run it. `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"`.

I have copied all the UcanAccess jar files into the folder in which my java code is. Have made `DSN`. Can anybody tell me why i am getting this message.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;    
import java.sql.ResultSet;    
import java.sql.Statement;    
import java.sql.SQLException;    
import java.sql.*;     

public class UCanAccessExample {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
      String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/UCanAccess/Personinfo.accdb";
      Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

      while(rs.next()){
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String add = rs.getString("address");
        String phone = rs.getString("phoneNum");
        System.out.println(name + "  " + add + "  " + phone);
      }
      con.close();
    } catch(Exception sqlEx){
      System.out.println(sqlEx);
    }
  }
}
```

[Image of folder in which my files are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cuO2.png)

Comment: How you run your program?

Comment: i ran my program in two ways none of them worked. first: "java UCanAccessExample"

Comment: Add the libraries to your classpath using Java -cp jar1;jar2;jar3 ...

Comment: second way " java -cp E:\UCanAccess\*:. UCanAccessExample

Comment: Just putting the JAR files in the folder where your Java source files are does not work. You must make sure those JAR files are in the classpath when you run your program.

Comment: Not working -cp UCanAccessExample :(

Comment: Jesper can you please tell me how to pur Jar files in class path ? syntax please

Comment: You could add the classes to the classpath with `cp`option. You could try `java -cp *;. UCanAcessExmple`

Comment: Why not in IDE which helps is setting the required libraries in classpath to execute ? Its absolutely a jar file missing case

Comment: Which IDE is better to use netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: I have no experience with netbeans and use Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA. I like both of them. Some coders told me that Netbeans is also nice

Comment: @VinayVeluri The best way to understand how everything works is just compiling and running your program on the command line. Then you can use one of the IDEs and know how to set classpath correctly. Otherwise, someday he has to run his program out of the IDE and he still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UCanAccess` driver in class-path.

[Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html) are ways to do it.

```
java.exe -classpath E:\lib\* Main
```

Comment: Just in case he's using an older version: stars work from as from Java 6 only. Before that you had to specify each jar file individually.